# Why do my bootstrap dropdown elems render badly?

Tags: html, angular, angular7, ng-bootstrap

I wanted to beautify my frontend with ng-bootstrap (installed via `npm install --save ng-bootstrap`)

```js
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  ...
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>
        Choose your playlist
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button
            class="dropdown-item" 
            *ngFor="let playlist of playlists"
            [class.selected]="playlist === selectedPlaylist"
            (click)="onSelect(playlist)">{{playlist.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it renders like that :

[image: render-failed]

Any ideas on how to fix that *insert many digusting synonyms* result ? :D

Comment: You seem to be using AngularJS and Angular at the same time.

Comment: Just FYI, using that kind of language triggers all sorts of alerts that will get you lots of negative attention. So just keep it cool next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add the `bootstrap.css`.

Just add the link to that in your index.html:

```
<link 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Also, you'll import the `NgbModule` from this path:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Not **NOT CALL** `.forRoot` on it.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your ref.